# iOS swift place a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

so i have an expansion table view cell and i'm trying to put a collection view inside a table view cell.  I google it and I get all sorts of objective-c however I'm trying to use swift...

see attached Xcode project, it's a swift and objective-c mix, but you'll get the idea.

In DarkViewController.swift you'll see it's tied to the main storyboard in the main.storyboard.

you can change it to ViewController for my attempt at putting a collection view inside a table view cell.

any ideas what I'm missing?

essentially I need a grouping mechanism to hold 1..n work items by a group:

Group 0
Work Item 1
Work Item 2
Group 1
Work Item 3
Work Item 4
...
Work Item n

and work item 1..n will be a list of work items [e.g. I use 8 work items, with various groupings].

[Sample Project can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqvla11aide350i/TestExpander.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I'm trying to place inside the ExpansionCell.infoView a collection view...so you can expand/un-expand it...

Comment: Are you wanting something similar to this? https://github.com/fawazbabu/Accordion_Menu

Comment: Caleb, I will look at your code it appears from running it it's doing something like I need to do so I'll get back with you after I absorb what your code sample is doing...I appreciate the response!

Comment: Caleb - that code repository was exactly what I was looking for...I thank you!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.